# How to modify master page in Sharepoint 2013 without enabling "publishin feature" and Sharepoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have restrictions at my level for using designer and "publishing feature".Is there any way to modify or upload a customized master page without them?

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the master page library with this url:`http://sp13/sites/yoursite/_catalogs/masterpage`. Then download the seattle.master file, make some customizations to this file. Then upload this seattle.master to the library again.